# How do I get rid of white space around a div set to width 100% that is only inside a body tag?

Tags: html, css

I have this meticulous problem,

1. I have a test html page whose body content is a single div tag.
2. I made the width and height of the div tag to 100% and colored the background red.

And I get irritated by the white space border around the div tag.
So my questions are:

1. What is the white space border around that div element?
2. How do I manipulate it OR get rid of it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use CSS to remove it.

[Before](http://jsfiddle.net/chUgA/) and [After](http://jsfiddle.net/chUgA/2/).

Just inserted

```
body, html {
    border: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
}
```

into the CSS. You have to set the height (and occasionally on mobile devices the width too) to 100% in order for the div to follow suit. Then changing the border, margin and padding to 0 (no px, etc) has stood me well for years. Although the floor is open to alternatives.